# Map dead_greek permanently to Compose+G?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

What is the best way in Ubuntu (17.10, 16.04) to permanently assign the <kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> keystroke to produce the <kbd>dead_greek</kbd> key?

The idea would be that I could then type combinations like

- <kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd>

To get uppercase Delta, lowercase pi, etc.

I found [this link](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2015/03/26/a-new-nice-trick-for-the-linux-keyboard-greek-letters/) from several years ago, but I'm not sure how best to incorporate that into my personal settings and whether that is still current information.

Comment: The `dead_greek` symbol is still present, and I think the example you link to still applies. Please note that it does not make use of `<Compose>`, though, but `<AltGr>` (or `<Right Alt>`). Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: In my Keyboard preferences, I have the Compose Key set to Right Alt. There is also an option for 'Alternative Characters Key' which is not set. I'm looking for an easy way to do this persisently, preferably via GUIs.

Comment: Are you using the compose key for other things? The easiest way is to not use the compose key for this, but let Right Alt keep its original behavior. If you let me know which keyboard layout you are using, it will be easier to show you.

Comment: Yes, I need the Compose key for °th€r thing§.

Comment: Ok. You need a key to choose 3rd level, and that's normally <Right Alt>. So either you can define some other key as the <Compose> key, or pick a non-standard key to choose 3rd level (the Alternative Characters Key option). Please let me know your choice in this respect, and (again) let me know which keyboard layout you are using.

Comment: I've got a US keyboard layout. I've previously been able to (temporarily) assign `dead_greek` to my `F6` key, but that gets in the way eventually. If possible, I want to use `Right Alt` as `Compose` and then use `Compose`+`G` to create `dead_greek`. But is that possible?? (I may need some clarification on what exactly 'third level' means).

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that. I submitted an answer which is a way to still achieve the behavior I think you want to see. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Third_and_fourth_level_choosers) explains third (and fourth) level.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to get the *behavior* you ask for:

1. Create the file `~/.XCompose`
2. Define the letters you want to be able to type. I give two examples:

   ```
   <Multi_key> <g> <d> : "δ" Greek_delta # GREEK SMALL LETTER DELTA
   <Multi_key> <g> <D> : "Δ" Greek_DELTA # GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA
   ```
3. Relogin

This allows you to type:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>G</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd> -> δ

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>G</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> -> Δ

But please note that this does not make use of the `dead_greek` symbol.